# Trying to pass key value pair to perl script via subprocess module

Tags: django, perl

I am trying to send key:value pair to perl script via sub-process module . I just tried with simple example it works fine. How can I pass key:value pair to perl script .....?

Ans also how can send multiple input fields value to perls script> Below is my code

view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, sys
import subprocess 

def ex(request):
   myName = 'Pervez'
   if 'firstname' in request.POST:
     myName = (request.POST['firstname'])
   p = Popen(['/home/pervez/Desktop/simplepage/simplepage/templates/ex.pl', myName],stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    p.stdin.close()
    result = p.stdout.read()
return render_to_response('ex.html', {'name': result},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

ex.html

```
{{ name }}
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="" NAME="SIGNUPFORM">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
<legend>Signup Form</legend>
<table>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><INPUT SIZE=20 NAME="firstname"> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td><INPUT SIZE=20 NAME="lastname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>User Name</td><td><INPUT SIZE=20 NAME="username"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><INPUT SIZE=20 NAME="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Verify Password</td><td><INPUT SIZE=20 NAME="vpass"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Your E-mail</td><td><INPUT SIZE=20 NAME="email_id"></td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="Reset" value="Clear Form">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

ex.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$|=1; # Flush immediately.

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
read STDIN, $form, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'};

foreach $pair (split('&', $form)) {

    if ($pair =~ /(.*)=(.*)/) {  # found key=value;

        ($key, $value) = ($1, $2);              # get key, value.
        $value =~ s/\+/ /g;                     # substitute spaces for + signs.
        $value =~ s/%(..)/pack('c',hex($1))/eg;
        $inputs{$key} = $value;                 # Create Associative Array.
    }
}

foreach $item (keys(%inputs)) {

    print "$item - $inputs{$item}\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Your perl script accepts data on STDIN whereas you are closing STDIN in your python script without sending any data there and that's why it didn't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

Perl script you provided is a basic CGI script.

As anydot mentioned, it expects data from STDIN.
But of `$ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH}` size.

If you want to get any output of this Perl script, you should uri-escape all data, join all keys and their values usung '=' character and then join pairs using '&' character.

And then set environment variable `CONTENT_LENGTH` to length of the string you obtained, run ex.pl and print the data to it's stdin.

The following Python code would do that:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

os.environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]="26";

p = Popen(['./ex.pl'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE);
p.stdin.write('foo=bar&baz=var+with+space\n');

p.stdin.close();
result = p.stdout.read();

print(result);
```

Probably dirty one, but I'm not a Python coder.